# Is there any tool that supports localization of JSF pages?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, intellij-idea, localization, properties-file

Is there something to help with localization of `*.xhtml` pages using `*.properties` files? I tried Eclipse, Netbeans and Idea. None of them provide autocomplete for localization bundle.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Internationalization in JSF works with a map of keys and values which is generated from a `*.properties` file. The name of the variable which contains the map, can be defined in the `faces-config.xhml`.

```
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>com.mkyong.welcome</base-name>
  <var>msg</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

In expression language, the values are then accessed from the map variable.

```
msg['example.key']
```

This is a nice tutorial for JSF internationalization:
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/

If IntelliJ can't do autocompletion for this feature, it's because the keys are only avaible during runtime.

Comment: Why downvote? Please tell me, what i've missunderstood or you need to know?